# Can I use macro/vba in acces/excel to sign a pdf with a certificate?

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf, certificate, signature

Currently I do this process:
I have pdf files I want to sign with a certificate that is installed in my PC
I do some checks about some data (not relevant) and if some conditions are fulfilled, I open the pdf file in the screen with a simple instruction like this:

```
FollowHyperlink (fichero_pdf_actual_temp)
```

And let windows10 deal with the application, it opens te file with acrobat reader and the user has it in his screen.

Then the user sees the pdf, signs manually with the installed certificate inside his pc with acrobat reader (inside acrobat going to tools, selecting certificates and signing, the saving) and that is pretty much all.

As often a lot of files have to be signed and I can do the needed checks myself with code (inside “normal” database tables, not relevant for the example) I wonder if there is some way to this signature with vba code.

Any orientation would be welcome. Even a partial idea that saves some "clicks" would be fine.

The certificate is provided by my company and asociated to my company email and user in the company network.

I am not an expert at all in this, but I hope the information is clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

my idea would be to use some commandline application like [PDFSign CL](https://www.pdfblog.at/2018/02/pdfsign-cl-command-line-application-to-sign-pdf-pdf-a-and-zugferd-as-well-as-timestamp-them/?lang=en) and call it via

```
Shell "PDFSignCL.exe /src=""c:\temp\doc_in.pdf"" /profile=""MySignProfile"""
```

You can deploy the .exe alongside your application.